# how to determine the encoding of scanf under linux?

Tags: c, linux, encoding

source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buff[100] = {0};
    char ch;
    int index = 0;
    scanf("%s", buff);
    ch = buff[index];
    while (ch) {
        printf("%2x", ch);
        ch = buff[index++];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. set locale to zh_CN.utf8, input '我', output '\xe6\x88\x91'(utf8 encoding of 我)
2. set locale to zh_CN.gb108030, input '我', the output did not change.

The problem is why the encoding was not changed? I thought it should be '\xce\xd2'(the gb18030 encoding of 我).

Or gnome-terminal(base shell) translate every input, no matter what locale in use, to utf8 encoding?

Thanks.

Comment: Changes of locale do not take effect immediately. Have you re-logged in or done something else like restarting your IME(input method editor) daemon? Also, what IME do you use?

Comment: try and restart the ime, which is fcitx, after export the LOCALE,but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your input system (in your case, gnome-terminal) produces input characters in a certain character encoding (the second part of the locale). That is usually set by some other means (command-line options, menu options, hard-coded into the program, etc.) and not by an environment variable. Therefore, there is usually one sane value for the character encoding in the locale environment variable to use: the one in which your input system produces the characters. You may change the language (the first part of the locale) more or less freely, but not the character encoding.